# LU Factorization of a full rank square matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

If **A** is an invertible matrix then a necessary and sufficient condition for the LU Factorization to exist is :

> If A is invertible, then it admits an LU (or LDU) factorization if and only if all its leading principal minors are nonsingular

Source : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition

How should one go about proving this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Always good to share your attempt/thoughts about the proof!

Comment: @JessePFrancis Well what is clear to me is this : Multiplying by **Li** is equivalent to a row operation. If a leading principal sub-matrix is singular then the reduced row echelon form for that sub-matrix would have a zero along the principal diagonal. ( And hence permuting the rows of **A** is required. **PA = LU** ). However I do not know how to write this down mathematically and hence I am not sure of its validity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle minor of a $n\times n$ matrix 
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&\dots&a_{1n}\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_{n1}&\dots&a_{nn}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
is a $k\times k$ ($1\ge k\ge n$) matrix obtained by deletion of the last $n-k$ rows and columns, i.e
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&\dots&a_{1k}\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_{k1}&\dots&a_{kk}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Rewrite $M$ as a block matrix, i.e.
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
A&B\\
C&D\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $A$ is a principle minor of $M$.

From this point I would try to show that the lower triangular matrix $L^M$ such that $L^MU^M=M$ can be written as a block matrix with a principle minor $L^A$ such that  $L^AU^A=A$, i.e.
$$L^M=\begin{bmatrix}
L^A&0\\
C'&D'\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

From this I would conclude that if a principle minor $A$ is singular we would have no $L^AU^A=A$ decomposition.

Comment: Suggestion: it is *principal* (roughly "the first"/"most important") instead of *principle* (usually used in the term "in principle")